# Expo Push Notifications - when app is in foreground it crashes iOS

Tags: react-native, push-notification, expo

I have an Expo app, and I'm trying to handle push notifications sent while the app is in the foreground. It works fine in Android, but iOS it's crashing the app as it's received.

I have a push notification being sent from a Rails server:

```
            params = ({
              to: token.expo_push_token,
              title: user.first_name,
              sound: "default",
              body: msg.body,
            })


            puts params
            puts params.class

            x = Net::HTTP.post_form(URI.parse('https://exp.host/--/api/v2/push/send'), params)
            puts x.body
```

I can see in the server it sends:

```
Hash
app[worker.1]: {"data":{"id":"9058abf3-7352-4181-a69d-0b5fc8a8525c","status":"ok"}}
4 TID-godk4ew98 ExpoPushWorker JID-51b823f8feeaf42c313e392e INFO: done: 2.005 sec
```

And if the app is closed, the push notification appears on the lock screen. If the app is open in the foreground, nothing happens.

I want to listen for notifications when the app is open, and I have this in App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import MessagesScreenRouter from './app/components/Router/MessagesScreenRouter';
import Sentry from 'sentry-expo';
import reducers from './app/reducers';

import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { Notifications } from 'expo';


export default class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      notification: {},
    }
    this._handleNotification = this._handleNotification.bind(this)
  }

  _handleNotification = (notification) => {
       console.log(notification)
       this.setState({notification: notification});
   };

  componentWillUnmount(){
    this._notificationSubscription && this._notificationSubscription.remove()
  }

  componentDidMount() {    
    this.notificationSubscription = Notifications.addListener(
      (notification) => this._handleNotification(notification),
    );
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex:1}}>
        <StatusBar hidden={true} />

        <View style={{height: 50, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
          <Text>Origin: {this.state.notification.origin}</Text>
          <Text>Data: {JSON.stringify(this.state.notification)}</Text>
        </View>

        <Provider store={createStore(reducers)}>
            <MessagesScreenRouter/>
        </Provider>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

I've tried many suggestions from tutorials all day, but I can not get this to work. What am I missing here?

Comment: Are you testing on iOS or Android?

Comment: @iuliu.net both. On the ios simulator, nothing happens - in fact my personal running it on expo, it crashes each time the notificaiton is expected to come in. On Android, the notification sound goes off, but I can't see any of the info in that console.log

Comment: Have you got this working @gwalshington or shall I try giving a helping hand?

Comment: @Siavas It's been awhile, but unfortunately I don't think I did. I ended up being able to make it work on Android in dev and just pushed to a private TestFlight, and it worked without issue. I don't think I ever got it working in iOS in dev. I will say, I now always boot with `exp start -m tunnel` which helped the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can't test it on simulator as expo docs states

> Note: iOS and Android simulators cannot receive push notifications. To test them out you will need to use a real-life device. Additionally, when calling Permissions.askAsync on the simulator, it will resolve immediately with "undetermined" as the status, regardless of whether you choose to allow or not.

Just run `exp publish` and test it on expo client. Also you have to call for permission using `Permissions.askAsync` in the first place.

Doc's sample work like a charm, check it out: https://docs.expo.io/versions/v28.0.0/guides/push-notifications#__next

Comment: The above is happening on an actual phone, not a simulator.

Answer (score 0):

Expo has likely been updated in that aspect since then, and now it might even be using the command you have mentioned in the comment (`exp start -m tunnel`). As foreground notifications are still not available on iOS so far (which [might have even caused your issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48437781/ios-expo-push-notifications-when-app-is-in-foreground#comment91995988_50013737) in the first place), this answer is rather for people looking to implement push notifications than fixing the issue above.

I have created a file downloader and previewer that shows both internal and external notifications on both OSes without running into such issues. The code [is available on GitHub](https://github.com/SiavasFiroozbakht/StackOverflow-47979921) and an elaboration is given in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54374890/5838198).

The most relevant code for this post is in regard to the use of [local notifications](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/notifications/) from Expo while the app is in background, and showing them in foreground using toasts from the [`react-native-toast`](https://github.com/crazycodeboy/react-native-easy-toast/) package. This functionality may be replaceable by Expo Notifications once [this feature](https://expo.canny.io/feature-requests/p/implement-foreground-notifications-on-ios-using-new-native-willpresentnotificati) gets implemented.

For completeness, here is the code for the project:

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, ScrollView, StyleSheet, Button, Alert, Platform, Text, TouchableWithoutFeedback } from 'react-native';
import { FileSystem, Constants, Notifications, Permissions } from 'expo';
import Toast, {DURATION} from 'react-native-easy-toast';

async function getiOSNotificationPermission() {
  const { status } = await Permissions.getAsync(
    Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS
  );
  if (status !== 'granted') {
    await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS);
  }
}

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // this.toast = null;
    this.listenForNotifications = this.listenForNotifications.bind(this);
    // this.openFile = this.openFile.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      filePreviewText: ''
    }
  }

  _handleButtonPress = () => {
    let fileName = 'document.txt';
    let fileUri = FileSystem.documentDirectory + fileName;
    FileSystem.downloadAsync(
      "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/expo/expo/master/README.md",
      fileUri
    ).then(({ uri }) => {
      console.log('Finished downloading to ', uri);

      const localnotification = {
        title: 'Download has finished',
        body: fileName + " has been downloaded. Tap to open file.",
        android: {
          sound: true,
        },
        ios: {
          sound: true,
        },

        data: {
          fileUri: uri
        },
      };
      localnotification.data.title = localnotification.title;
      localnotification.data.body = localnotification.body;
      let sendAfterFiveSeconds = Date.now();
      sendAfterFiveSeconds += 3000;

      const schedulingOptions = { time: sendAfterFiveSeconds };
      Notifications.scheduleLocalNotificationAsync(
        localnotification,
        schedulingOptions
      );
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
        Alert.alert(error);
    });
  };
  listenForNotifications = () => {
    const _this = this;

    Notifications.addListener(notification => {
      if (notification.origin === 'received') {
        // We could also make our own design for the toast
        // _this.refs.toast.show(<View><Text>hello world!</Text></View>);

        const toastDOM = 
          <TouchableWithoutFeedback 
            onPress={() => {this.openFile(notification.data.fileUri)}}
            style={{padding: '10', backgroundColor: 'green'}}>
            <Text style={styles.toastText}>{notification.data.body}</Text>
          </TouchableWithoutFeedback>;

        _this.toast.show(toastDOM, DURATION.FOREVER);
      } else if (notification.origin === 'selected') {
        this.openFile(notification.data.fileUri);
      }
        // Expo.Notifications.setBadgeNumberAsync(number);
        // Notifications.setBadgeNumberAsync(10);
        // Notifications.presentLocalNotificationAsync(notification);
        // Alert.alert(notification.title, notification.body);
    });
  };
  componentWillMount() {
    getiOSNotificationPermission();
    this.listenForNotifications();
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    // let asset = Asset.fromModule(md);
    // Toast.show('Hello World');
  }
  openFile = (fileUri) => {
    this.toast.close(40);
    console.log('Opening file ' + fileUri);
    FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(fileUri)
    .then((fileContents) => {
      // Get file contents in binary and convert to text
      // let fileTextContent = parseInt(fileContents, 2);
      this.setState({filePreviewText: fileContents});
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.buttonsContainer}>
          <Button style={styles.button}
            title={"Download text file"}
            onPress={this._handleButtonPress}
          />
          <Button style={styles.button}
            title={"Clear File Preview"}
            onPress={() => {this.setState({filePreviewText: ""})}}
          />
        </View>
        <ScrollView style={styles.filePreview}>
          <Text>{this.state.filePreviewText}</Text>
        </ScrollView>
        <Toast ref={ (ref) => this.toast=ref }/>
      </View>
    );
            // <Toast
        //   ref={ (ref) => this.toast=ref }
        //   style={{backgroundColor:'green'}}
        //   textStyle={{color:'white'}}
        //   position={'bottom'}
        //   positionValue={100}
        //   opacity={0.8}
        // />
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
  },
  buttonsContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
  button: {
    flex: 1
  },
  filePreview: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 10,
  },
  toastText: {
    color: 'white',
    padding: 5,
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
  },
});
```

package.json: Currently using forked repo, [switch back](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-simple-toast) when [feature becomes available](https://github.com/crazycodeboy/react-native-easy-toast/pull/58).

```
{
  "name": "local-notification-with-ios",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "No description",
  "author": null,
  "private": true,
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "^32.0.0",
    "react": "16.5.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-32.0.0.tar.gz",
    "prop-types": "^15.5.7",
    "react-native-easy-toast": "git+https://github.com/SiavasFiroozbakht/react-native-easy-toast.git#6eed52f4d64c796cb49bdafcd7b3986cf5975d62"
  }
}
```